# Force a yielded function to error for unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, generator

I am trying to unit test this Koa middleware:

```
function * onError(next) {
    try {
        yield next
    } catch (err) {
        this.status = 500
        this.body = err.message
    }
}
```

I wish to trigger the catch block but I can't seem to get `yield next` to cause an error.

If this was a non generator method I would do something like this:

```
function method (next) {
    try {
        next()
    } catch(err) {
        this.xxx = 'Error = ' + err.message
    }
}

function next() {
  throw new Error('Boom!')
}

const context = {}

method.bind(context)(next)

console.log("Expect context to contain xxx with error message")
console.log(context.xxx)
```

Back to the generator function, because `next` isn't called (it's yielded to), the catch isn't entered.

I can get access to `next`, but calling it isn't enough, it throws its error outside of the try:

```
function next() {
    throw new Error('Boom?')
}

const iter = onError(next)

const yielded = iter.next() // Moves the generator to the first, and only, yield

console.log(yielded.value) // Our next

yielded.value() // Error is thrown here, not in the generator.
```

So, the question I'm looking to answer is, can I force execution into the catch block, and hence test my error handling?

If anything isn't clear, ask in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something because I haven't gotten really in-depth with generator functions yet, but I don't see any way `yield next` can throw in the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-generator-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation (scroll down slightly to "`yield` *AssignmentExpression*"). The only opportunity I see for throwing there is in evaluating *AssignmentExpression*, but evaluating `next` in your example is not going to throw.

Comment: So if I don't have the ability to control `next` in the try block, I can't enter the catch?

Comment: I'm saying that my read of the spec (which could be incorrect) is that `yield next` will never throw, regardless of what the `next` function does (indeed, regardless of whether it's a function at all). `yield next` will suspend the generator and return the value of `next`. That's all. It doesn't **run** `next`.

Comment: Sorry, misread your first comment. That's what I'm seeing. I've tried passing in an error, undefined and a function, both plain and generator. As you said, it doesn't proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @loganfsmyth's mention of `iterator.throw()`, I came up with this:

```
// Function to test
function * onError(next) {
    try {
        yield next
    } catch (err) {
        this.status = 500
        this.body = err.message
    }
}

// Context we expect to be updated in the catch block
const context = {}

// Get the generator
const iter = onError.bind(context)()

// Move generator to first yield
iter.next()

// Pass an error into the generator
iter.throw(err)

// Check the context
expect(context.status).to.equal(500)
```

I had tried other combinations of calling `throw` and `next` on the iterator but not this.

Inline comments explain what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pass the error back into the generator, e.g.

```
try {
  yielded.value();
} catch (e){
  iter.throw(e);
}
```

Calling `.throw` on a generator will cause a value to be thrown from the currently-suspended `yield` statement.

Comment: Thanks @loganfsmyth - You prompted me to go back and try `throw` again!